let's encrypt certificate permission issue with postgres
I'm using certbot, on Ubuntu 22, to generare ssl certificate. All works fine but all certificate is generated in the following folder
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/cert.pem
The problem is that user and group that are both root.
If I try to use one of certificate to configure postgres to use SSL, I get permission denied error.
I would avoid to copy cert in other directory every time is generated. Is there a way to change group for generate certificate?
Best regards

Generally, there are tho approaches for services to be able to read the certificate and the private key. The real concern is how to keep the private key secure so that no-one else than the services using it can read it.

Some services (e.g. Postfix) runs a master process as root in order to bind to privileged ports (<= 1024) as well as to read secrets from configuration files including the private keys. They then fork unprivileged processes for whatever the service is doing.

Some services (e.g. PostgreSQL) do not run any of their processes as root. Therefore, they cannot read the files under /etc/letsencrypt/live/, and the files should be copied to a place where only the service in question can read it.


As multiple services might need the same certificate & private key it is not wise to alter the permissions of the /etc/letsencrypt/live/ directly, but to create as many copies of the files as required. With Let's Encrypt, this should not be a manual process, but automated as deploy hooks (see Renewing certificates).
Pavel Lazureykis has written a tutorial on Automatic SSL certificates for your PostgreSQL; phases 10–12 instruct how to build the deploy hook:


Let’s automate certificate update process. I’ll create a new script at /usr/bin/update_certs.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Paths to certificate and key files
CERTIFICATE="/etc/letsencrypt/live/pgtest.uptime-monitor.io/fullchain.pem"
PRIVATE_KEY="/etc/letsencrypt/live/pgtest.uptime-monitor.io/privkey.pem"

# Destination directory for PostgreSQL certificates 
PG_CERT_DIR="/etc/postgresql/16/main"

# Copy certificate and private key
sudo cp "$CERTIFICATE" "${PG_CERT_DIR}/pgtest.crt"
sudo cp "$PRIVATE_KEY" "${PG_CERT_DIR}/pgtest.key"

# Set permissions and ownership for certificate and private key 
sudo chmod 600 "${PG_CERT_DIR}/pgtest.crt"
sudo chmod 600 "${PG_CERT_DIR}/pgtest.key"
sudo chown postgres:postgres "${PG_CERT_DIR}/pgtest.crt"
sudo chown postgres:postgres "${PG_CERT_DIR}/pgtest.key"

# Force PostgreSQL to reload config:
sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT pg_reload_conf();"


Set this script as executable:
chmod +x /usr/bin/update_certs.sh


Install the script as a hook in certbot. It will be executed every time certificate is updated by certbot:
sudo certbot renew --force-renewal --deploy-hook /usr/bin/update_certs.sh




